# JSON Parsing, structure assistance

Tags: android, json

```
JsonFactory f = new MappingJsonFactory();

                        JsonParser jp = f.createParser(res);

                        JsonToken current;
                        current = jp.nextToken();
                        if (current != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                            System.out.println("Error: root should be object: quiting.");
                            return;
                        }
                        while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                            String fieldName = jp.getCurrentName();
                            // move from field name to field value
                            current = jp.nextToken();
                            if (fieldName.equals("row")) {
                                if (current == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {

                                    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {

                                        JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
                                        Log.e("KFF", node.get("col0").asText());

                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("KFF", "Error: records should be an array: skipping.");
                                    jp.skipChildren();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.e("KFF", "Unprocessed property: " + fieldName);
                                jp.skipChildren();
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

- `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fichart.finance.yahoo.com%2Ftable.csv%3Fs%3DYHOO%26a%3D11%26b%3D10%26c%3D2011%26d%3D10%26e%3D10%26f%3D2013%26g%3Dd%22%3B&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=`

I'm currently using the above to parse JSON responses from the web (USING THE JACKSON JSON PARSING LIBARY) , however i'm at a loss at to how to parse nested json arrays such as the following, i.e. how to go down into each json array until 'row' and then be able to read each 'colx' eliminating 'unprocessed property'

Sorry about the horrendous quality of English in that, it's late and i'm at a loss in terms of describing it.

Comment: Could you post the JSON response you're getting back.  Because I dont' think I'm seeing the same thing you are when I call that URL.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rhD2d9fx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.  Disclaimer - totally untested.  This will put you in the right direction though.

```
// Assuming the json is in a String called jsonString

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("row");

int arrayCount = jsonArray.length();
for(int i=0; i < arrayCount; i++){
      JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      String col0 = jsonData.getString("col0");
      String col1 = jsonData.getString("col1");
      // etc, etc ...
      // put those values in arrays or whatever here.
}
```

Comment: is that using jackson? It's a huge dataset so ill be running into memory issues loading it into memory with json objects.

Comment: oh god, my mistake, i'm not sure i even mentioned that.

Comment: Ummm, yeah... you may have wanted to mention that.

Comment: So sorry! perhaps i should sleep on it and return tomorrow.